# Date time custom format

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have a date like this

```
{
"date": "2021-08-05",
"start_time": "11:00:00",
"end_time": "12:30:00"
}
```

I need to make a format like `DD:MM:YYYY 00:00:00 - 00:00:00`

So it will be like `05-08-2021 11:00:00 - 12:30:00`

I know we can parse the date like this

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, "dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But is it possible to convert the date to this format

```
DD:MM:YYYY 00:00:00 - 00:00:00
```

Comment: A .NET `DateTime` only has one time instance. You will have to create a user-defined type for this, and implement a `Parse` method.

Comment: ^What Mark said. I would also suggest overriding the .ToString() method to write it our in the format you want.

Comment: Do you have a class or is this about reading from json?

Comment: How would you show that the end time is 'tomorrow' ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the input is the following json.

```
{
"date": "2021-08-05",
"start_time": "11:00:00",
"end_time": "12:30:00"
}
```

In order to read it we can use a class, for example:

```
public class
{
  public DateTime date {get; set}
  public TimeSpan start_time {get; set}
  public TimeSpan end_time { get; set}
}
```

To print it in your desired format you can override the `ToString()` method:

```
public override string ToString()
   => $"{date.ToString("dd:MM:yyyy")} {start_time} - {end_time}";
```

BTW. Make sure that your serialiser is configured to know if `2021-08-05` means *5th of August* or *8th of May*.

Comment: I have date as a DateTime and use it to signify the start date & time.

Answer (score 0):

Best suggestion I have would be to concat the different date parts together and then parse a date time out of that.

It's worth mentioning that you'd have to create two DateTimes here...

```
var start = sDate["date"] + sDate["start_time"];
var end = sDate["date"] + sDate["end_time"];

DateTime.TryParse(start, out DateTime startDate);
DateTime.TryParse(end, out DateTime endDate);
```

Once done, you can output the dates in the correct format:

```
var output = startDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
output += " - " + endDate.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

This should get you the format you want for your output.
HTH

Comment: _"This should get you the format you want for your output"_ vs _"I need to make a format like DD:MM:YYYY 00:00:00 - 00:00:00"_ - not exactly. Different separator on the Date and no " - " between the times.

Comment: @Fildor happy now?

Comment: I know, I am nitpicky sometimes. Thanks for the edit!